# Issues with showing www in the addess bar

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, vps

I have recently purchased a VPS and a domain. The VPS runs Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache 2.4. When I go to the browser and type `http://example.com`, the index page correctly loads up. The same thing happens if I put `www` before the domain name, but in that case the `www` disappears.

How do I make `www` stick in the address bar and possibly redirect all `non-www` requests? This I critically important to me since I have bought an SSL certificate for the domain with`www` included.

I tried to modify DNS settings in order to acheive that, but so far all my attempts have failed miserably.

My current (working) settings are:

```
=== A records ===
[empty]     31.14.131.29
localhost   127.0.0.1
webmail     62.149.158.92
webmail     62.149.158.91
www         31.14.131.29

=== AAAA records ===
None

=== CNAME records ===
None
```

Also I have tried to use `.htaccess`, but apparently the requests were caught up in a loop.

This is the first time I set up a VPS and I feel a bit lost. Can you please show me the right way to do it?

**Edit**: `000-default.conf` file content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.grandegiove.com

    ServerAdmin grandegiovestore@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit**: `.htaccess` content file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^grandegiove.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.grandegiove.com/$1 [l,r=301,nc]
```

and still www does not show up.

Comment: What is your Apache configuration?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Added `000-default.conf` configuration file.

Comment: Your server most probably makes a redirect from www to non-www. This isn't really a bad thing, in fact, search engines usually reduce your ranking if you provide identical content on different domains (yes, www and non-www qualify as different domains for this). You should make one of the entries your primary and keep the redirect from the other to your primary. The redirect itself can happen in several places, the apache main config, a htaccess file or even a script.